# Landform design/3D in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, lidar, arcscene, cad

Im a self taught ArcMap user working in a small business, so no one to bounce problems off.

My aim is this: I would like to be overlay different surfaces, manipulate them, and display them. The image below has been made in MapInfo:

[image]

Its a mine dump (LIDAR) with a section of the new design (CAD) projected over the top. NOte that it intersects with the natural surface, and has a backing elevation grid.

My investigations/experimentation thus far have been this:

- Using Sketchup to make design surfaces
- Importing the image into ArcScene
- Placing and orientating the design using 3D Editor functions.

So far so good, but when I try and edit/manipulate the design in ArcScene or ArcMap, it appears not to have any attribute table/geometry associated with it. When I try and save the design in Sketchup as CAD I get the same problem.

I would be happy if anyone could provide some basic steps to get toward my goal. Any answer with more detail would be fantastic.

Comment: Normally, you add survey hard lines to existing TIN surfaces to modify them in ArcGIS but you want to be able to manipulate the surface manually by pulling and stretching. Is that correct? Sketchup may have a meltdown with surfaces that have so many faces. Can you confirm that you can successfully manipulate your surface in Sketchup?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, something like that should be possible following these steps:

In ArcGIS:

- Convert LiDAR raster to TIN.
- Convert TIN to Multipatch Feature.
- Export Multipatch Feature to Collada (.dae).

In Skethcup:

- Import Collada file.
- Alter/edit 3D surface.
- Save as Sketchup or export to a new Collada file

In ArcScene:

- Add original Multipatch feature.
- In 3D Editor -> Start Editing.
- Select Multipatch and "Replace with Model" from drop down menu.
- Navigate to your edited sketchup or Collada model.

Existing multipatch will be replaced with the 3D model edited in Sketchup.

That's the theory.  Unfortunately, this only works well with FULLY enclosed and relatively simple multipatch features such as buildings. This is a great option if you want to add some details to your 3D buildings.

Although you can convert a surface to TIN and then a Multipatch feature, and provided you can actually open the result in Sketchup (may require an intermediate step of re-saving the collada file in a 3rd party application such as TurboCAD or Meshlab) you will ultimately NOT be able to load and "replace the model" with the final edited surface. This is likely because this technique only works with fully enclosed, simple, multipatches and not 2.5D surfaces.

You can however edit surfaces in ArcGIS by adding hardlines but although possible with a lot of manual tinkering and interpolating lines, etc. those are not easy to create in the ArcGIS ecosystem.